# subcaption color with the subfigure package

Tags: floats, color, subfloats, subcaption

To define the caption color in my document, I am using

```
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[font={small,color=ocre}]{caption}
```

Which works perfectly, but currently facing the following two problems:

1. Subcaptions are not colored (I am using the [subfigure](http://ftp.twaren.net/Unix/TeX/CTAN/obsolete/macros/latex/contrib/subfigure/subfigure.pdf) package, so I can't use the same code as above)

[image]

2. When a citation is included in the figure caption , it is not colored.
   [image]

Does any one have some solutions or hints?

After the request, here is a minimum working example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage[numbers,square]{natbib}  
%The following is uesd to make the caption colored
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{ocre}{RGB}{1,160,233}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[font={small,color=ocre}]{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx,subfigure}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}  % hyperlinks
      \usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}  % hyperlinks
      \hypersetup{
           colorlinks=true, 
          allcolors=black,          
          citecolor=black,
          linkcolor=black,
      }

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
  @book{Knu86,
    author = {Knuth, Donald E.},
    year = {1986},
    title = {The \TeX book},
  }
\end{filecontents*}

\bibliography{\jobname} % if you’re using BibTeX


\begin{document} 

\begin{figure}[hb]
\centering     %%% not \center
\boxed{\subfigure[Subfigure One]{\label{fig:SubfigureOne}\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{../../Desktop/StackExchange/Test.pdf}}}

\boxed{\subfigure[Subfigure Two]{\label{fig:SubfigureTwo}\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{../../Desktop/StackExchange/Test.pdf}}}

\caption{Comparison between Subfigure One and Subfigure Two. \autoref{fig:SubfigureOne} shows the difference for the complete data range, and \autoref{fig:SubfigureTwo} as displayed in \cite{Knu86}}
\label{fig:OverAllFigure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you show us a fully MWE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Code

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage[numbers,square]{natbib}  
%The following is uesd to make the caption colored
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{ocre}{RGB}{1,160,233}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[font={small,color=ocre}]{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx,subfigure}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}  % hyperlinks
      \usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}  % hyperlinks
      \hypersetup{
           colorlinks=true, 
          allcolors=black,          
          citecolor=black,
          linkcolor=black,
      }

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\AtBeginEnvironment{figure} {
  \hypersetup{
           colorlinks=true, 
          allcolors=ocre,          
          citecolor=ocre,
          linkcolor=ocre,
      }
}

\newcommand{\boxedcolor}[2]{%
  \boxed{\color{#1}#2}%
}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
  @book{Knu86,
    author = {Knuth, Donald E.},
    year = {1986},
    title = {The \TeX book},
  }
\end{filecontents*}

\bibliography{\jobname} % if you’re using BibTeX


\begin{document} 

\begin{figure}[hb] 

\centering     %%% not \center
\boxedcolor{ocre}{\subfigure[Subfigure One]{\label{fig:SubfigureOne}\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{exercises.png}}}

\boxedcolor{ocre}{\subfigure[Subfigure Two]{\label{fig:SubfigureTwo}\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{exercises.png}}}

\caption{Comparison between Subfigure One and Subfigure Two. \autoref{fig:SubfigureOne} shows the difference for the complete data range, and \autoref{fig:SubfigureTwo} as displayed in \cite{Knu86}}
\label{fig:OverAllFigure}
\end{figure}

Another reference to Figure~\ref{fig:OverAllFigure} with a black hyperling.

\end{document}
```

## Document

[image: Colored captions]

## Explanation

1. The problem is, that you defined a black color for hyperlinks using `\hypersetup`. You can change the link colors *locally* using `\hypersetup` again at the begin of every `figure` environment. I think the most comfortable way of doing this is using `\AtBeginEnvironment` of the package `etoolbox`.
2. To change the color of the subfigure captions, I defined a new command `\boxedcolor`. It allows you to change the color inside the box and also affects subfigure captions. Depending on whether you always want to use `ocre` as you color, you could also define `\boxedcolor` it with one argument

   ```
   \newcommand{\boxedcolor}[1]{%
     \boxed{\color{ocre}#1}%
   }
   ```

   which leads to shorter usage: `\boxedcolor{...}`.

   Alternatively, you could append `\color{ocre}` to `figure` using `\AtBeginDocument` like I did it with `hypersetup` before. This would be the most comfortable solution, but it also leads to a colored box (which is not desired, I expect).

Answer (score 0):

Just put parenthesis

```
\textcolor{white}{{Subfigure 1}}
```